# How can I click on a link which opens an image, then only display part of that image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a large image of a map with points of interest on it.

What I want is to have a button on a page of text, when the button is clicked it opens the map image in a different window. What I then need is for the image to only display the relevant portion of the map showing the point of interest mentioned on the original page with the button.

I've found ways to show a certain section of the map using  and  coordinates, or using the map as a sprite sheet, or using CSS background-postion, but I can't find a way to implement this on clicking the button.

Ideally I'd like to achieve this with just CSS because there are going to be quite a few pages linking to this image.

Here is a small guide of what I'm tring to achieve.

[Image showing how this works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKDCJ.jpg)

```
    <style>

.map-one {
  background: url('map.jpg');
  background-position: center bottom;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}

</style>

<button><a class="map-one" href="map.jpg">Click</a></button>
```

This is an exmaple of some code I've tried, which is obviously wrong, but I don't know how to apply the css style to the image when clicking on the link.

Comment: Can you isolate the issue that's preventing you from tieing it to the button? You're on the right way with using height, width and background-position to slice out the correct part of the image, but without code to look at or a more in depth explanation, we have no idea why you can't bind it to the button. When the button is clicked, you should calculate which values you need to show the correct image slice and pass these to the second page. ( url parameter, postMessage, ... ). Then the second page just has to look at these values and change the CSS on the image inline.

Comment: Please provide a code example to show what you have tried.

Comment: I tried doing the css background position, and then added the class to the anchor tag in the button, but nothing happened when I clicked the button.  Everything I've found online has had the image being displayed in a div in the same page, but my image is to be a separate page that gets opened on click of the button.  Obviusly I don't want to have separate images being called in for every section of the map.

Comment: Hence you need to pass the correct data from the first page to the second. Easiest way is just including a query or a hash fragment inside the url and have the second page look at these so it knows whcih aprt of the map to show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to calibrate the values until you have achieved the exact area you want, but the code will be pretty much like this:

### Main page

```
<a href="map.html" target="_blank"><button> <!-- Map page path -->
    CLICK ME!
</button></a>
```

### Map page

```
<style>
    div.map {
        background-image: url('map.png'); /* image file path */
        background-position: 70px 90px;   /* image position  */
        width: 200px;                     /* image size      */
        height: 200px;
    }
</style>
<div class="map"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you this seems to work. I just have to work out the position of my points of interest now. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Well it doesn't work with just pure css, you have to pass some parameters to your new window.
So i will assume that you pass an X and Y coordinate to the new window and you have that available on your new page.

First you need to wrap the "Map" to give it a viewport. If nothing else is on the page you can theoretically use body:

```
<div id="mapviewport">
<div id="map">
</div>
</div>
```

So if you want the user to be able to explore the map you can use `overflow: auto` on the viewport, otherwise use `overflow: hidden`.
The map container gets the width/height of the map. The map is provided via `background-image` on  the map-container.

Now to scroll to the right position, use .`scrollTop` and `.scrollLeft` on the mapViewport to scroll the map to the right spot.